# how to use onRestart() in android

Tags: android

i have an application that have 2 languages and I let the user chose the language from
activityD but when he get back to the first activity its still using the default language 
how can I use onRestart() to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question.

First, let's understand what is `onRestart` and when exactly should we use it.

Consider the activity lifecycle:
[image]
([Source](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/images/activity_lifecycle.png))

We can see that `onRestart` is only called when the activity has gone in `onStop` state. I.e., when the activity isn't visible to the user. Thus, when `onStart` is called in your activity lifecycle, to determine if this is a first-time start of the activity or the activity has just been restarted from the back stack, you can use `onRestart`

This can be done by setting an instance variable of type `boolean` in `onRestart`. With this knowledge, hope you can understand if this is something that you'd like to employee for the solution you're trying to implement or not.

Answer (score -1):

Hope i understand you correctly , so what you need is to restart the Activity?
Code:

```
public static void restartActivity(Activity act) {    
        Intent intent=new Intent();
        intent.setClass(act, act.getClass());
        act.startActivity(intent);
        act.finish();    
}
```

Comment: where do you want me to call this method? will it be before i called another activity?

Comment: you pass it like this,
restartActivity(this); //from current activity

Comment: i wrote it before the activity end it and print some log.v and it give me infinte loop

Comment: i also tried to do this                protected void onRestart() {
     String TAG = "MyActivity";
     Log.v(TAG, "in restart" + TAG);
     restartActivity(this);
    }
    public static void restartActivity(Activity act) {    
        Intent intent=new Intent();
        intent.setClass(act, act.getClass());
        act.startActivity(intent);
        act.finish();    
}

Comment: what if you do this like so: MyActivity.this